# How can I separate the first and last name of a cell?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

If cell A1 contains [Jones,Mike], how can I get it to separate but still use the first name as text in the other cell? Yes, text to columns would work greatly, but it does let me use the first name in a formula.

Comment: http://maddox.xmission.com/keyboard4.jpg

Comment: What is it you want here - a VBA function that splits the name up?

Comment: @ KennyTM- sorry i didnt notice
@Rosarch- thanks but this cpu wont let me look at the link
@Phil- ok, i was sent a huge excel document to fix. At first it was simple, i used text to columns to seperate the first for the surname, but i had to add diff parts of diff cells to make a "roster number"; example a1 is bob, b1 is james, c1 is ricky, and d1 is a ssn#(123-45-6789), roster number would be bjr6789. I have the formula to do that but that formula will not let me use the first name. does this help you at all?

Answer (score 0):

With name in A1, for surname:

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND(",",A1,1)-1)
```

For first name(s):

```
=RIGHT(A1,FIND(", ",A1,1)-2)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Ex: John Doe**

First name:

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1,1)-1)
```

Calculate first name length from left by Finding the " " (Space) character position in the cell string, -1 to remove the space in the counting.

Surname:

```
=RIGHT(A1,(LEN(A1)-FIND(" ",A1,1)))
```

Calculate Surname string length by first finding the value where surname starts. Full cell length minus first name + the space.

**Ex: Doe,John**

Surname:

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND(",",A1,1)-2)
```

First name:

```
 =RIGHT(A1,(LEN(A1)-FIND(",",A1,1)))
```